# I don't want to give height to tabBarview how would i do it?

Tags: flutter

In below code I don't want give height to tabbarview. I want to give it infinite height means height as per data.
when I don't give height to tabbarview it gives me error as follows:

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.

Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand.
The relevant error-causing widget was
TabBarView
lib\…\ProductPage\product_type_page.dart:495
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack

```
Container(
              height: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[100],
                border: const Border(
                  top: BorderSide(width: 1, color: 
                        kDefaultBorderColor),
                  bottom: BorderSide(width: 1, color: 
                       kDefaultBorderColor),
                ),
              ),
              child: TabBar(
                controller: _controller,
                indicatorColor: Colors.grey,
                labelColor: kDefaultTitleFontColor,
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(15.0),
                ),
                tabs: const [
                  Tab(
                    text: 'Description',
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    text: 'Overview',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            SizedBox(
              height:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
              child: TabBarView(controller: _controller, children: [
                ProductDescription(
                  descriptionData: productDetails.typesDescription,
                ),
                ProductDescription(
                  descriptionData: productDetails.typesDescription,
                ),
              ]),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a property for a container called `constraints`. Set that property to `BoxConstraints.expand()`. Also remove the height of the container. Also it would be better if you put `TabBar()`and `TabBarView()` which is wrapped with the `Expanded()` widget inside of a `column()` widget. So you can remove the `SizedBox()`.

Comment: I did but it gives error like: ════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Column
lib\…\ProductPage\product_type_page.dart:130

Comment: If I remove singlechildscrollview then its working. but i want singlechildscrolview